# Find $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{|\sin x||\cos x|}{x}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Find the limit of $$\begin{equation*} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{|\sin x||\cos x|}{x} \end{equation*},$$

What is the value of $|\sin x|$ & $|\cos x|$?

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: The left and right limits are different.

Comment: $|\sin(x)|$ is the absolute value of $\sin(x)$...  Do you know know how to compute an absolute value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that when $x \approx 0$, $\sin x \sim x$.

Calculating the left limit, $${|\sin x \ | \over x} \approx -1,$$ and for the right limit, $${|\sin x \ | \over x} \approx 1.$$

Can you calculate the limits now? Does the two-sided limit exist?